# Why duplicate function names in mod.rs as another .rs file?

Tags: rust, module

For example, have module within /xyz/ sub-directory.  Inside the directory are two files, mod.rs and network.rs say.

Why do mod.rs and network.rs have the same function names, but different code within the functions?  Is there any reason for this?  I thought mod.rs was just basically a defintions file to declare a module, and specify which other .rs files within the sub-directory should be treated as their own creates / modules.

Any help?

Comment: Which crate are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are referring to a design decision made by a specific crate. You are correct in assuming there is no special consideration given by the compiler to function/type/ident names in separate files/modules.

That being said it seems likely that what you are referring to might be using [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html). Conditional compilation lets the compiler decide if a given piece of code is compiled or not. You will usually see this used to handle which implementation of a function is used when compiling code on different operating systems since it is often it too inefficient or simply impossible to check at runtime. Some library authors might also decide to add an implementation that it can  fallback to instead of throwing a hard error.

Here is a quick example of why `xyz` might want to have 3 different implementations of `foobar`.

```rust
// xyz/mod.rs

mod windows;
mod unix;

// If this crate is compiled on windows re-export the contents of windows.rs
#[cfg(windows)]
pub use windows::*;

// If this crate is compiled on unix/linux re-export the contents of unix.rs
#[cfg(unix)]
pub use unix::*;

// If not on either windows or unix provide a default implementation to use instead
#[cfg(not(any(windows, unix)))]
pub fn foobar() -> i32 {
    panic!("This function is unsupported on the current os")
}
```